# In reactjs, how do I distribute components horizontally across an encompassing div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

So I'm new to react and for the life of me I can't figure out how to make something like this:
[tic-tac-toe grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PFLv.png)

I'm having trouble making a row component that renders a div with three different square components, distributed horizontally across the div. When I compile my code all the squares in a row are fixed to the same spot. How do I fix this, please?

my current code:

**App.css**

```css
.Row {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 35%;
  right: 50%;
  top: 25%;
  
  width: 25%;
  height: 25%;

  display: flex;

  
}
.Square {
  position: absolute;
  
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border-color: #99ccff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: xx-large;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}
/* .Row {

} */
```

**Square.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export function Square(props){
    // Square is rendered by App

    return(
        <div >
            <button className='Square'> X </button>
        
        </div>
               
    );
}
```

**App.js**

```js
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { Row } from './components/Row';

function App() {
  // App renders Row
  return (
    <Row />
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Row.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Square } from './Square';

export function Row() {

    return(
        <div className='Row'>
            <Square />
            <Square />
            <Square />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: There's a tutorial on the React website that creates a functional tic-tac-toe game.  Should help you re: creating the game board.  https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to remove `position: absolute` in `Square` class:

```css
.Square {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border-color: #99ccff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: xx-large;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}
```

Comment: let's gooo!! this also helped, thanks!! 
Can you explain why it worked tho?

Comment: Yes, because when you set `positions: absolute` it is mean that this element will ignore all other elements, so all of your squares ignored each other and was at the same place. But when you removed this property it will work as `position: relative` and they will see the positions of each other and placed correctly. For more information about position you can read [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp).

If it is not hard for you please approve my answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className={"row"}>
      <Square />
      <Square />
      <Square />
    </div>
  );
}

export function Square(props) {
  // Square is rendered by App

  return (
    <div className={"column"}>
      <button className="Square"> X </button>
      <button className="Square"> X </button>
      <button className="Square"> X </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Styles.css file**

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Read this article to get more understanding about flex: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: thank you so much, I guessed the solution might have something to do with flex, and I've been meaning to read up on flex. Thank you!!

Comment: quick question: does the css you wrote for the app class automatically affect all instances of the app component? if so, can we write css for any custom defined component we make the same way you wrote the css for app?

Comment: Yes, it is. you can avoid affecting CSS classes globally by using CSS modules in React js. https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/